# Django domain forwarding

Tags: django, heroku, subdomain

I have a Django site which will show different things depending on the subdomain visited.

So you will see "A"-type things if you go to a.mysite.com but "B"-type things if you go to b.mysite.com.

I do this by gathering the subdomain in the request and using that to filter.

What I want to be able to do is allow any other domain to point at these subdomains (like, for instance, heroku can do) but still allow me to do the filtering in the above way.

Is that possible?

If so, how would I go about it?

I assume that, if a user comes to my site on theirdomain.com (which points at a.mysite.com) then I won't have "a" in the subdomain so how do I know they want to see "A"-type things?

Comment: can you explain what filtering you are doing?

Comment: It's just going to use the subdomain string to filter on a particular model in the db. There'll be much, much more than that in the end but I don't think there's any need to go into details on that as it'll just muddy the waters of this initial problem really.

Answer (score 0):

If other people redirect their domain to your subdomain, then everyone would be visiting your domain, `a.yourblog.com` The only way that another domain `someotherblog.com` would be serving the content of your subdomain `a.yourblog.com` is you setting an url redirection in the DNS configuration of `yourblog.com`, and redirect `a.yourblog.com` to the url of `someotherblog.com`.

So in essence  `a user comes to my site on theirdomain.com`is not something that would happen from what I understand. They can only be redirected to your domain, which is no different from visiting your domain directly.

Comment: I'm talking specifically about the case that's similar to the way heroku does it's sites. You can create a site at your-app.herokuapp.com and use an A-record to point yourdomain.com at it. The URL the user is using is yourdomain.com. They have no idea that it's pointing at another URL.

In this case, I wouldn't have access to the subdomain I need to detect that I need to filter on, would I?